# Overlay background color and image

Tags: html, css, menu, overlay

I am trying to overlay a background color (blue) on top of a background image.  I have a menu that I want to appear above the background color. I've tried using the z-index property, but it is not working for me.  I'm sure it has something to do with the properties of the menu, but I'm stuck.  I've tried putting the menu inside of another div, but I can't get the div dimensions correct.

This is my index page.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Practice.css">

</head>

<body  background="http://localhost/jim/BatikVilla/Background.jpg">

<div id='blue'>
<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
 <li class='active'><a href='index2.php'>Home</a></li>
 <li class='has-sub '><a href='Product.php'>Products</a>
    <ul>
       <li class='has-sub '><a href='Men.php'>Men</a>
          <ul>
             <li><a href='Sarong.php'>Sarong</a></li>
             <li><a href='Shirt.php'>Shirt</a></li>
     <li><a href='MenSlipper.php'>Slipper</a></li>
          </ul>
       </li>
       <li class='has-sub '><a href='Women.php'>Women</a>
          <ul>
             <li><a href='DarGyi.php'>DarGyi</a></li>
             <li><a href='LongDress.php'>Long Dress</a></li>
     <li><a href='WomenSlipper.php'>Slipper</a></li>
          </ul>
       </li>
    </ul>
 </li>
 <li><a href='About.php'>About</a></li>
 <li><a href='Contact.php'>Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

and my CSS

```
<style>
@charset "UTF-8";
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oxygen+Mono);


#blue{
height:400px;
background-color:blue;
}

#cssmenu{
clear:both;
float:left;
margin:0;
padding:0;
width:100%;
background:#fff;
position:relative;
}

div ul {
float:right;
list-style: none;
margin:0;
padding: 0;  
position: relative;
right:50%;
}
div ul:after {
content: ""; clear: both; display: block;
}
div ul li {
float: left;
margin:0 0 0 1px;
padding:0;
position:relative;
left:50%;
top:1px;
}
div ul li:hover {
background: #4b545f;
}
div ul li:hover a {
color: #fff;
}

div ul li a {
display: block; 
margin:0;
padding:.6em .5em .4em;
font-size:1em;
line-height:1em;
background:#ddd;
color: #444; 
text-decoration: none;
}

div ul ul {
display:none;
position: absolute; 
top: 2em;
left:0;
right:auto;
width:10em;
}
div ul li:hover > ul {
display: block;
}

div ul ul li {
left:auto;
margin:0;
clear:left;
width:100%;
}

div ul ul li a {
padding: 15px 40px;
color: #fff;
}   

div ul ul li a:hover {
background: #4b545f;
}

div ul ul ul {
position: absolute;
left: 100%;
top:0;
}
```

Please help me if you can.

Comment: are you able to give a little more clarity into what you're trying to achieve? from what it sounds (and looks) like, you want a background image on your page, and then a DIV element with a blue background in the page structure. is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  Basically, imagine a box within a box.  The outside box is the page and the background image for that entire box is 'x'.  The inside box has a background color (blue).  The inside box also displays a drop down menu, and perhaps more in the future.  I'm not sure if using a DIV element is the only way to achieve it or not, but sure, with a div element.  I hope that helps clarifiy.

Comment: Okay, sounds fairly simple. I'll post an answer and we can continue from there.

Comment: Just make sure that the drop down menu stays as is, and centered.  I have made some progress, but only at the expense of my menu.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm rewriting the entire snippet you provided from scratch to help clean it up and explain things to you a little bit. While I'm doing that, are you able to provide something like a screenshot of what you're attempting to do (including the menu position, etc)? Just simple boxes would be fine - you can use a service like www.tinypic.com to upload it easily. // edit: don't worry about explain the submenus, just a box for where the navigation unordered list should be in relation to the parent element is fine

Comment: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2r41sn4&s=6 This is the link.  So what I want is a white background to lay over the background image.  I want it centered, and for the drop down menu to appear over it.  at the moment the white background color is a horizontal strip, and it does not change regardless of how I edit the dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

I hope can help you. Try this css :

```
#blue{
    position: absolute;
    /*left: 0; top:0; bottom:0; right :0;*//* For FULL SCREEN OVERLAY */
    left: 5px; top:5px; right :5px;/* SCREEN OVERLAY w/ 5px Margin */
    height:400px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 225, 0.6);    
}
```

And you can add contents inside element ID : blue.

Here the demo : http://jsfiddle.net/Tv97Y/

Comment: this is the perfect quick fix for OP. sorry i wasn't able to provide a complete rewrite for you, **Jimbob**; I got called away for about an hour. inbox me if you need more information about this.

Comment: Thanks, I see that it works in fiddle, but for some reason it still doesn't work on my computer.  I still get a horizontal bar behind the menu of the background color.  I'm using Linux Ubuntu 12.04 and Firefox 18.0.1.  Don't know if this matters. Any ideas?

Comment: @Jimbob : I use openSuse 11 and Firefox 3.6.2 and Firefox 18, all of them displays correctly. Try checking your coding, there may be tags that have not been closed.